# Finding out what's slowing down ASP.NET pages

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a rather 'heavy' ASP.NET page, and currently the speed is fairly unacceptable - there is a *lot* of database communication, and displaying large grids. But I effectively want to find out what's actually causing the most slowdown, and working from there.

Are there any tools built into Visual Studio 2008, or any third party tools, that'll allow me to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [ASP.Net Trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y13fw6we%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to figure out what is slowing down in the page.

Answer (score 2):

Another good tool and easy to use, https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/yslow/

Not aimed directly at code, but is very helpful with resources

Comment: I think he is referring to server-side issues

Comment: Agreed, but it explores compression and static image stores. In a world were we expect data to be displayed instantly every millisecond counts :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard about [profiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29)?

My favorite tool is RedGate's [Ants Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/).

Answer (score 0):

An easy approach is using [`Stopwatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx). Something like this:

```
void SlowMethod()
{
   Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
   timer.Start();
   //a lot of DB operations
   timer.Stop();
   //record timer.Elapsed

   //restart the timer and check another piece of code
   //at last find the bottle neck of the method
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What Muhammad said - add tracing to your code to identify the slowest bits.

Also if you think db activity could be responsible, you could run [SQL profiler](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/step-by-step-an-introduction-to-sql-server-profiler/5054787) to identify any long running queries - this will also help you correct indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

Visual Studio Team System has a built in profiler. In VS 2010 this is available in premium and above.

Otherwise [**red-gate**](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) has a good profiler available. (for a fee).

Try using the [**tracing functionality**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386420.aspx) built into asp.net.

Try using client side developer tools like [**Yslow**](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) and [**Page Speed**](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/) or [**fiddler**](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see the requests for a page and their size and timings.

If you haven't already done so, make sure your server is serving **gzipped content**. This is an easy win.

Use [**SQL Server Profiler**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx) to profile your database requests.

Answer (score 0):

There are many profiling tools available, I personally like ANTS Profiler, it is quite good.  Check out the following link for more information on out to use it: [ANTS Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/supportcenter/Content?p=ANTS%20Profiler&c=ANTS_Profiler%5Carticles%5Cprofiling_web_app.htm)

And here is a link to the ANTS Profiler download: [14 Day Free Trial](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/download)

But if there is a lot of database communication, it is most likely the cause.  Try minimizing the number of database calls and improving the performance of your database queries.

Also make good use of cacheing!